# Shorten duration before drag?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

How can I make the drag & drop functionality activate faster? I want to shorten the duration between the mousedown and the drag and drop activating; so that the user is able to move the item faster.

I currently have it implemented using a `ListView` with `CanDragItems` set to `true` and `AllowsDrop` on my receiving `Grid`.

I have been searching, but I can't seem to find my answer anywhere.

I now have added a small animation when the item is touched (`PointerPressed`), which animates the view, so that the user has something to look at when they are waiting for the drag and drop to activate.